# Oracle JSBC кодировка

Tags: oracle, jdbc, кодировка

Как задать кодировку `UTF-8`?

Код подключения к базе :

```
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("er");
        }
        Connection cn = null;
        String str = "[";
        try {
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@999.99.9.999:1521:meta", "*******",
                    "*****");
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            st.close();
        }
```

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@999.99.9.999:1521:meta?charsetUTF8` - этот вариант не помогло

Comment: если это не из за ссылки соединения, вы проверяли саму базу? на чем она стоит и какие у него кодировки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодировка клиента не задается в строке коннекта, при соединении с базой драйвер читает настройки базы - NLS_LANGUAGE и NLS_TERRITORY. По этим параметрам драйвер перекодирует сообщения из локали клиента в локаль базы. Изменить это можно через установку переменной окружения NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
Подробнее - [How JDBC Drivers Perform Globalization Support Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/advanc.htm#1003420)